# TagHelper with Wildcard HtmlTargetElement, is this possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have written a simple TagHelper for Bootstrap Tooltips:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("button", Attributes = "tooltip")]
public class TooltipTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Tooltip))
        {
            return;
        }

        output.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "tooltip");
        output.Attributes.Add("data-original-title", Tooltip);
    }
}
```

Currently I have activated it via the `HtmlTargetElementAttribute` for the `button` element. Since I want, that this taghelper is processed on any element, if the `tooltip` Attribute is present, I tried to setting up a wildcard:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("*", Attributes = "tooltip")]
```

This doesn't seem to work, e.g I get no syntax highlightning when I type `tooltip` on any element.

Is it somehow possible to make a TagHelper work on all tags without repeating `HtmlTargetElementAttribute` for every possible Tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, it is exactly working this way:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("*", Attributes = "tooltip")]
```

But Intellisense is not inteligent enough to recognise it. The resulting page has both attributes assigned to it.

I worked arround by adding additional target elements in Debug Mode, since Intellisense is very important to me.

```
#if DEBUG
    [HtmlTargetElement("button", Attributes = "tooltip")]
#endif
    [HtmlTargetElement("*", Attributes = "tooltip")]
```

Comment: Six years later, but since I'm here anyway... you don't actually need to specify an element type at all (at least you don't anymore, it may have changed since your original question). You can now just use `[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "tooltip")]`.